# Will it to be tough to catch up if I missed 3 classes of 3 courses?

Tags: masters, engineering

I lost my.passport before leaving for masters in the USA. I'm doing an engineering management degree and I will miss the first 3 classes of the 3 courses Ive enrolled in.

How tough will it be to catch up or is it risky to pursue this as I've visa and university requirements that mandate a GPA above 3.0.

Comment: We can not answer your question because we do not know the courses, this is why there are so many close votes. Nonetheless Nate Eldredge gave a good answer and maybe you can re-phrase your question to fit the answer.

Comment: Three classes could be three hours worth of material (not a huge deal) or nine (a bit more of a deal).

Answer (score 9):

It depends greatly on the courses.  In some cases it might be easy, in others it might be very difficult.

Contact your professors immediately, let them know the situation, and ask what you should do.  They might:

- send you notes
- suggest material for you to study on your own
- offer extra help when you get back
- suggest that you drop the course